# Flow type definitions for Puppeteer prevent using default export?

Tags: puppeteer, flowtype, flow-typed

Consider puppeteer's `launch()` method. The [usage guidelines in the Puppeteer readme](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#usage) recommend to use `const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')` and then `puppeteer.launch()`:

> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
>
> (async () => {
>   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
>   const page = await browser.newPage();
>   await page.goto('https://example.com');
>   await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
>
>   await browser.close();
> })();
> ```

And Puppeteer itself [exports an instance](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/cba0f98a2ac7edd3c2bffd0ac53185877403da6b/index.js#L40), which seems to further confirm the default export is meant to be used:

> ```
> module.exports = new Puppeteer(__dirname, preferredRevision, isPuppeteerCore);
> ```

However, the [Flow type definitions for puppeteer ≥1.12](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/e24d577ea33b4193b012231820c152d4f15535d7/definitions/npm/puppeteer_v1.12.x/flow_v0.104.x-/puppeteer_v1.12.x.js) use `declare export function launch()` and **don't** include a default export, so **Flow requires me to write `import { launch } from "puppeteer"`** instead of `import puppeteer from "puppeteer"`.

**But using the named import yields `TypeError: Cannot read property '_launcher' of undefined`.** Similarly, we can confirm this doesn't work with a simple test (Node v10.15.0, puppeteer 1.19.0):

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
puppeteer.launch();  // works
```

```
const { launch } = require("puppeteer");
launch();  // TypeError: Cannot read property '_launcher' of undefined
```

(Presumably this is because `const { launch } =` gives me an unbound method — `this === undefined` when called.)

---

**Attempt 2**: In Flow you can also use a **namespaced import** `import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer"`, but [it seems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) this explicitly forgoes access to the default export, instead yielding `TypeError: puppeteer.launch is not a function`.

(I'm less familiar with TypeScript, but the [DefinitelyTyped defs for Puppeteer](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/puppeteer/index.d.ts) also use `export function launch()` rather than a default export. That said, [they seem intended](https://www.lewuathe.com/using-puppeteer-in-typescript.html) to be used with `import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer"`, although I'm not sure why this would work when it doesn't in Flow; perhaps a difference in how TypeScript handles ES6 modules?)

---

So, am I holding it wrong, or are the Flow type definitions wrong? (In which case, how has nobody else encountered this problem?)

Comment: I would suggest opening up an issue with either DefinitelyTyped or flow-typed to see what the correct import method is given the current type definitions.

Comment: Thanks, yep I also recently filed https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/3538.